# How to search string using regular expression for string contains characters alphabets and special characters like -, () using python

Tags: python

I want to search dynamically some string contains case insensitive and some string contains special characters like (TM), (R) how to search those strings

```
with open(logfile) as inf:
                for line in inf:
                    if re.search(string,line,re.IGNORECASE):
                       # print 'found line',line
```

I wanted to add re.IGNORECASE,re.escape() are giving error, How to solve it

Comment: it is working for case insensitive but if u give strings like "Stack(R) Overflow" it is not searching but it is contained in the file. So how to search those strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i put this into python console...

```
>>> re.search(re.escape("Stack(R) Overflow"), "Hey bro, Stack(R) Overflow", re.I)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb778adb0>
```

..i got correct result.